# HtmlAgilityPack returning an empty list of child nodes

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape some stuff from amazon, and can't get past the login. HtmlAgilityPack is returning an empty list of child nodes. Here's what the HTML of the form looks like (redacted for readability)

```
<form name="signIn" method="post" novalidate action="https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin/..." class="auth-validate-form auth-real-time-validation a-spacing-none">
    <input type="hidden" name="appActionToken" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="appAction" value="SIGNIN" />
    <input type="hidden" name="openid.pape.max_auth_age" value="ape:MA==">
    <input type="hidden" name="openid.return_to" value="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="prevRID" value="...">
```

Here's my code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var amazonHomeUri = new Uri("https://www.amazon.com");
        var amazonHomeDoc = GetHtml(amazonHomeUri);
        var signInNode = amazonHomeDoc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("#nav-link-yourAccount").First();
        var signInUrl = signInNode.Attributes["href"].Value;
        var amazonSignInDoc = GetHtml(new Uri(amazonHomeUri, signInUrl));
        var loginForm = amazonSignInDoc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("form[name='signIn']").First();
        var postUrl = loginForm.Attributes["action"];

        //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
        //THERE ARE CERTAINLY INPUTS INSIDE THE FORM
        foreach(var input in loginForm.SelectNodes("input"))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(input.Attributes["name"]);
        }
    }
    private static HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GetHtml(Uri uri)
    {
        string html;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        return doc;
    }
}
```